# $(k,l)$ shuffle and wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

Consider the shuffle

$$(f \wedge g)(v_1,\ldots, v_{k + l}) = \sum_{(k,l) - \text{shuffles} \ \sigma} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) 
f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma (k)})g(v_{\sigma_{(k + 1)}}, \ldots, v_{\sigma_{k + l}})$$

I don't understand why this sum has $k+l\choose k$ terms instead of $(k + l)!$ terms. More specifically how do we know that the count of
$\sigma(1) < \sigma(2) < \sigma(3) \ldots < \sigma(k)$ and
$\sigma(k + 1) < \ldots < \sigma(k + l)$
has $k+l\choose k$ ways of counting them?

Comment: by $(k,k+l)$ you mean $\binom{k+l}{k}$? the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Yes. I mean the binomial coefficient.

Comment: You need to place $k$ red indices and $l$ blue indices into $k + l$ ordered boxes. Once you have chosen the colour of each box, there is only one way of placing the indices into their coloured boxes, since the indices must be placed in increasing order. Therefore the number of shuffles is the number of ways of choosing $k$ from $k + l$, which is the binomial coefficient $\binom{k + l}{k}$.

Comment: Note you have a few typos. You typed $\binom{k+1}k$ instead of $\binom{k+l}k$ and then the symbol upside-down.

Comment: @Joppy what I don't understand is what happens to the l blue indices why don't we choose k + l choose l instead of k?

Comment: Choosing $k$ items from $k + l$ items is equivalent to choosing $l$ items (once you have coloured in $k$ red, the rest must be blue). A reflection of this fact is that $\binom{k + l}{k} = \binom{k+l}{l}$.

Comment: Sure ok. Yes. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the formula for the wedge product of an alternating $k$- and $l$-form:

$$
(f\wedge g)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) = \sum_{\sigma \in (k,l)-\text{shuffles}} \text{sgn}(\sigma)f(v_{\sigma(1)},v_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})
$$

It can be helpful to start with the formula which uses all permutations, which is perhaps more familiar:
$$
(f\wedge g)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}} \text{sgn}(\sigma)f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})
\tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Let $\sigma\in S_{k+l}$ and consider $(\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(k))$. This is a list of $k$ distinct integers between $1$ and $k+l$, hence there is a unique permutation $\tau \in S_k$ such that $\sigma(\tau(1))<\sigma(\tau(2))\ldots\sigma(\tau(k))$. Similarly, there is a unique permutation $\rho\in S_l$ (viewed as the permutations of the $l$-element set $k+1,\ldots,k+l$) such that $\sigma(\rho(k+1))<\sigma(\rho(k+2))<\ldots<\sigma(\rho(k+l))$, and hence $\sigma\circ(\tau\circ\rho)$ is a $(k,l)$-shuffle, and in fact this shows that the $(k,l)$-shuffles are a transversal for the right cosets of $S_k\times S_l$ in $S_{k+l}$. This implies immediately that there are $(k+l)!/k!l!$ such shuffles.

Moreover, applying this to ($\dagger$) if we write $\eta_{\sigma} = \sigma\circ(\tau\circ \rho)$ for the $(k,l)$-shuffle associated to $\sigma$, then since $f$ and $g$ are $k$- and $l$-alternating,

$$
\begin{split}
(f\wedge g)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) &=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}} \text{sgn}(\eta_\sigma(\tau\circ\rho)^{-1})f(v_{\eta_\sigma\circ\tau^{-1}[(1)},\ldots,v_{\eta_\sigma\circ\tau^{-1}(k)}).\\
&\phantom{asfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf}g(v_{\eta_\sigma\circ\rho^{-1}(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\eta_\sigma\circ\rho^{-1}(k+l)})\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}} \text{sgn}(\eta_\sigma(\tau\circ\rho)^{-1})\text{sgn}(\tau)\text{sgn}(\rho).\\
&\phantom{asfasdfasdfasdfasd}f(v_{\eta_\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\eta_\sigma(k)})g(v_{\eta_\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\eta_\sigma(k+l)})\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}} \text{sgn}(\eta_{\sigma})f(v_{\eta_\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\eta_\sigma(k)})g(v_{\eta_\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\eta_\sigma(k+l)})
\end{split}
$$

Now the summation in the last line is over all of $S_{k+l}$, but the summands corresponding to $\sigma$ in the same $S_k\times S_l$ coset are equal, hence the sum is in fact:
$$
k!l! \sum_{\eta \in \text{Shuffles}(k,l)} \text{sgn}(\eta)f(v_{\eta(1)},\ldots,v_{\eta(k)})g(v_{\eta(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\eta(k+l)})
$$

Thus using the sign idempotent to make $f\otimes g$ into an alternating tensor, sums over $(k+l)!$ terms, but in fact they can be grouped into collections of $k!l!$ terms which are all equal. Thus anti-symmetrizing using shuffles gives an alternating for which gets rid of the "obvious" repetitions in the anti-symmetrizing formula using all of $S_{k+l}$.